# Determine the year of the previous occurrence of a given date range

Tags: algorithm, date

I recently had to create a function that would determine the year of the previous occurrence of a given date range. The given date range will always be less than 1 year in length and if the range crosses over the new year, the function should return 2 different values: the start year and the end year. See the following examples:

```
If the date range is 10 Jun - 20 Jun:
    If current date is 01 Apr 2016: Return 2015, 2015
                       15 Jun 2016: Return 2015, 2015
                       01 Aug 2016: Return 2016, 2016

If the date range is 20 Dec - 10 Jan:
    If current date is 02 Jan 2016: Return 2014, 2015
                       01 May 2016: Return 2015, 2016
                       25 Dec 2016: Return 2015, 2016
```

I implemented my own python function to do this:

```python
# Returns the years for the previous occurrence of the given period
def _get_last_years_for_period(start, end):
  current_year  = datetime.date.today().year
  current_month = datetime.date.today().month
  current_day   = datetime.date.today().day

  if (start['month'] < end['month']) or ((start['month'] == end['month']) and (start['day'] < end['day'])):
    # Period does not overlap between 2 different years
    if current_month > end['month']:
      return [current_year, current_year]
    elif (current_month == end['month']) and (current_day > end['day']):
      return [current_year, current_year]
    else:
      return [current_year-1, current_year-1]
  else:
    # Period overlaps over 2 different years
    if current_month > end['month']:
      return [current_year-1, current_year]
    elif (current_month == end['month']) and (current_day > end['day']):
      return [current_year-1, current_year]
    else:
      return [current_year-2, current_year-1]
```

However, I can't help but feel that there is a more elegant way of implementing this. I'm curious to see if anyone has any ideas for a faster, more elegant or even easier-to-read implementation. If you do, please share (don't worry about writing it in Python, use whatever you want).

Comment: What if one of the dates in the range is Feb. 29?

Comment: Your code looks okay. You can tidy it up and boil it down to four cases if you extract the check whether a date comes after another in the same year into a separate function.

Answer (score 0):

I'd simplify it by defining a simple comparator:

```py
def comes_before(month_day_1, month_day_2):
  return (month_day_1[0] < month_day_2[0]
          or (month_day_1[0] == month_day_2[0]
              and month_day_1[1] < month_day_2[1]))

def get_years_for_period(month_day_1, month_day_2):
  now = datetime.date.today()
  year2 = now.year if comes_before(month_day_2, [now.month, now.day]) else now.year - 1
  year1 = year2 if comes_before(month_day_1, month_day_2) else year2 - 1
  return [year1, year2]
```